# A custom WSGIRequestHandler.log_message in Django?

Tags: python, django, logging, request

I would like to filter out the request log from successful static requests, however, this seems to be not as trivial as I expected. I ended up changing the installed code, but I hope there is a better solution. How can I do it?

[Original code on GitHub](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/servers/basehttp.py#L199)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with [django-devserver](https://github.com/dcramer/django-devserver) with its [SlimWSGIRequestHandler](https://github.com/dcramer/django-devserver/blob/master/devserver/utils/http.py#L26)